# Meaning of underscore in Groovy

Tags: groovy

What is the meaning of an underscore in a Groovy template?

```
if(_.isString(document.get....))
    ....
```

Comment: Is this Grails or just Groovy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_` is a valid identifier in Groovy (and Java)

Ie: this:

```
def _ = 13
println _
```

Prints `13`.  You'll have to give a bit more context to find out what is setting `_` in your given situation

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for [JENKINS-43749](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43749).